# Edit a CGPath's "vertices"?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation, cgpath

If a triangle is created in a CGPath, and I desire to move one of the corners of the triangle relative to the other two corners, it seems I need to create a new CGPath...

That doesn't seem right.

Is there a way to simply edit the position of a corner of that triangle within an existing CGPath?

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for iterating over all elements in the CGPath, called [`CGPathApply()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathApply), however, you would need to create a new mutable path in order to change the existing path.

In short, as you can iterate over the various elements of the path, you can modify them before adding them to a new mutable path, which once completed will resemble the original, but with the changes you made in `CGPathApply()`.

EDIT: In short, no, you can't edit elements of an existing `CGPath`, you can only copy them over (potentially modifying them during the copy) to a new path.

Comment: The questions is this: Is there a way to simply edit the position of a corner of that triangle within an existing CGPath?

Comment: Keyword being "within".

Comment: Then the answer is still the same, no, you can't mutate existing elements in a CGPath, but you can modify them before re-applying them to a new path.

Comment: I don't understand, I did say no to your original question - "however, you would need to create a new mutable path in order to change the existing path" and then I reiterated, as you were still asking the same exact question. Let me answer it the third time, you can't alter elements that have already been applied to a CGPath, you have to copy them over (potentially modified) to a new path.

Comment: None of that is an explicit "No" to the question. I don't see how that's so hard to do.